# Pass project to another developer without changing package name

Tags: appcelerator

I have to pass a project to another developer that has to continue maintenance and development. I gave him the package with the project contents but he's unable to build it because the guid is bound to my developer account. Can I unregister the app so he can freely continue development?
Does he have to create a new app with a new package name? This way he has to publish a new app in stores and not update the old ones (which we wouldn't like to do).

Thank you
Alex

Answer (score 2):

If the app is not using Appcelerator Analytics or Arrow you can simply remove the `<guid>` in `tiapp.xml` and re-register the app to the new organisation.

If you do use Arrow/Analytics you need to contact support@appcelerator.com to have the app transfered.

Comment: I have it on my list of apps in platform.appcelerator.com, but on the tiapp.xml it says that no appcelerator services are enabled. So they only have to remove guid line and rebuild, correct?

Comment: Yes, try to remove guid parameter and rebuild the project until Studio asks you to register your app to a new guid.

If you do not use Appcelerator Analytics or Arrow, then one more solution is that create a new project and remove all tags except guid tag from new tiapp.xml file and copy paste all tags (except old guid) from old tiapp.xml file to new tiapp.xml file.